# opening PDF using Flex in a web application

Tags: apache-flex, pdf

Is there a way to open a PDF file whixh exists on some server using flex in a web application?

Comment: You could look at one of the several varients on this question already rather than adding another one.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31077/256544

Answer (score 3):

You can make Flash use the browser to open the PDF. Use "_blank" as target to open it in a new window.

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

...

    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(urlOfThePDF), "_blank");
```