# embed PDF inside Flex App

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, flex3, flex4

How to embed PDF files into Flex App? Do I really need to transfer them to swf files first?

Comment: are we talking web flex or air app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was surprisingly more complicated than it should have been (considering they are both Adobe products).

You don't need to convert the pdfs to swf files.

This page has practically all the details you need on how to do this http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=PDF_1.html

You need to keep in mind that the client machine has to be PDF capable (i.e. have Adobe Reader installed). You will also need Acrobat Pro (or whatever they call it now) to do the more in-depth PDF scripting (javascript-in-pdf stuff).

---

To add to this (because I misread the question), to open a PDF file in Flex, you have two options. The first is, as you said, to convert the file to a swf or other format. The other is to open it using the user's PDF reader. Calling `navigateToURL(new URLRequest('<http-link-to-pdf-file>' ) );` should do it (assuming the user has a pdf reader installed).

Comment: That's for AIR applications only. The question doesn't explicitly states that platform

Comment: As Ben said, this only suits AIR applications, and I am more interested in embedding PDF into Flex (Web) applications.

Comment: @Maria. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077/how-do-i-display-a-pdf-in-adobe-flex